# What's the word for a design at the side of a page?

Tags: single-word-requests

Printed pages have headers and footers at the top and bottom. But there are often designs or graphics that run from the top of the page to the bottom, such as the stripes in this simple example:

[image: Here is a simple example]

Is there a professional word for this kind of element? Or even just a simple one?

A sample sentence would be:

> How can I insert a ________ into my document?

Comment: A **graphic panel**, perhaps?

Comment: I admit this is not what you are looking for, but an apostil (or apostille) is a note or annotation in the margin.

Comment: Specifically the stripes might be called a *vertical rule*, but I would simply refer to it as a *margin design*.